# Bootstrap-datepicker not triggering 'show' event on when I change year for half-yearly calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap-datepicker[text](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for rendering half yearly calendar by manipulating monthly calendar as shown in the code-

`

```
  $.fn.datepicker.dates['halfyears']={

  days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
  daysShort: ["Sun", "Moon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
  daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
  months: ["H1", "H2"],
  monthsShort: ["&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;H1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" , "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;H2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"],
  today: "Today",
  clear: "Clear",
  format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
  titleFormat: "MM yyyy",
  weekStart: 0
};

let that=this;
$('#date-picker-input').datepicker({
    format: "MM yyyy",
    minViewMode: 1,
    autoclose: true,
    language: "halfyears",
    forceParse: false,
}).on("show", function(event) {
 $(".month").css({"width" : "100%"}).each(function(index, element) {
   if (index > 1) $(element).hide();
 });

 })
```

`

[image of calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtLEQ.png)
the issue is when I click on left arrow of calendar to change the year 'show' event is not triggered.

Ideally it should be triggered.
can you tell what am I missing?

Comment: _"when I click on left arrow of calendar to change the year 'show' event is not triggered"_ - why should the `show` event trigger _at this point_? If the date picker was not _already showing_ - then what arrow would you be clicking ...?

Comment: I just want to bind a function on click on prev arrow? Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The only event that appears to be relevant, is `changeYear`, https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changeyear Can't tell if you are actually the "decade view" though.